# Docker container failing unexpectedly

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run docker image mongodb-36-centos7 which can be found here https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/mongodb-36-centos7. I've followed their suggested command but keep getting the attached error.

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2im7V.png)

I can see files being populated in the volume I created in my C:\temp\mongodb folder so it has permissions to write there.

docker run --name dummy4 --rm -e MONGODB_USER=simpleUser -e MONGODB_PASSWORD=abc123 -e MONGODB_DATABASE=myDB -e MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpassword -v c:\temp\mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb/data a850527afa31

Comment: try to publich the port with `-p 27017:27017 ` in your command

Comment: I added it and still getting exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your port# 27017 is free or not.

Comment: ran a netstate -ano command. Didn't see 27017 appear anywhere so I assume its free?